# Comparing UTF-8 and UTF-16 strings . both looks visibly same but shows difference for special characters like apostrope etc

Tags: node.js, postgresql, oracle, unicode, iso-8859-1

I am comparing same string stored in source and destination databases .

**source database** - oracle UTF-16 encoding.
**destination database**- postgres UTF-8 encoding.

While the string looks visibly same. but when i fetch the string from source and destination in a node js utility and compare it.then it shows the difference on special character like apostrophe.

I ran this query in oracle to see unicode code point of apostrophe-

```
select chr(146) from dual
```

it returns apostrophe.

and in postgres-

```
select chr(146)
```

it returns some other special character.

how do i compare strings coming from these databases?

Comment: `CHR` or `CHAR` is for ASCII on all databases. It returns the character that corresponds to the ASCII value 146 in whatever codepage is used by the database/server

Comment: but why char(146) returns different values in postgres and oracle?

Comment: Because they use different single-byte codepages. You'd get different values between different Oracle databases, or different PostgreSQL databases, if those used different settings. What are you actually trying to do? Why are you comparing strings? Whatever the real problem is, `CHR(146)` isn't relevant, nor does it have anything to do with Unicode

Comment: If you want to see the *Unicode* character, use [NCHR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NCHR.html#GUID-3A1BDD54-6C0B-4067-99C5-A439C0F8D561) in Oracle

Comment: I suspect PostgreSQL is treating `146` as a Unicode code point. 146 in Unicode is [a non-printable character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). In Latin1 it's the right apostrophe. `NCHR(146)` in Oracle should return an unprintable character as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: obviously these methods don't handle (only) ASCII, or using 146 as input would be an error that they'd report. ASCII only goes up to 127 and anything above that indicates some other (probably ASCII-based) encoding.

Comment: Step back, and try to describe your actual requirement, remembering that we don't know *anything* about your code which you don't show us. It sounds like you have some node.js code, and you want to connect it to two databases, and do something with the strings coming out of them. But you haven't shown us any of that code, or what exactly it needs to output, or what it currently outputs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so the usecase is, we have some mapping rules between oracle and postgres. we send data from oracle to postgres and we need to ensure that data is intact between the two DBs. thats why we have this node utility that comapres the data and raise a flag if there is any mismatch . now the data that i am comparing visibly looks same in both DBs but when compared in node js. it shows difference wherever there is apostrope

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is the underlying server encoding for both the DBs. i cant really change the encoding. and the data looks same . i am getting issue only with apostrophes. other alphabets are same in both DBs

Comment: Postgres documentation:chr ( integer ) → text

Returns the character with the given code. In UTF8 encoding the argument is treated as a Unicode code point. In other multibyte encodings the argument must designate an ASCII character. chr(0) is disallowed because text data types cannot store that character.

Comment: You're using the wrong function to test for the wrong thing. Unicode is Unicode. No matter how Unicode codepoints are translated to bytes, the same codepoint always corresponds to the same character. If you get different characters it means either one or both sides are *NOT* using Unicode. In this case, `CHR(146)` isn't Unicode. If the Oracle text is stored as Unicode, either as nvarchar or a Unicode encoding, you're testing the wrong thing altogether

Comment: `In UTF8 encoding the argument is treated as a Unicode code point` and since you get a square instead of an apostrophe, it means PostgreSQL (either the server or client) are set for Unicode, not eg Latin1. If you use `NCHR(146)` in Oracle you should get the same

Comment: What's the column collation in Oracle? That's what matters. Each column can have its own, different collation

Comment: This question is lacking vital information: How do the strings differ in Javascript? How did you configure the respective database connections? How are the strings encoded in the respective databases?

Comment: An Oracle database has always 2 character sets. The `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`. Function `CHR` returns character in `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is most likely **not** UTF-16

Comment: "... when compared in node.js, it shows difference wherever there is apostrophe ..." <- **that** is the part we need more information on. Forget about your attempts to recreate the problem by converting integers to characters, and go back to your real problem. Click [edit], show us some JS code, and explain what you're seeing when you run it. (Alternatively, forget about the node.js part, and ask for an explanation of what `CHR()` and `CHAR()` are doing; you might learn something interesting, but it almost certainly won't help you solve your original problem.)

Comment: By the way, this temptation to focus on an attempted solution rather than the original problem is a common trap, and is known as [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/237313). That's why I began my first comment with "step back" - take a breath, think about what you're really interested in help with, and start again with a clear description of the problem.